# Android Studio: "Could not reserve enough space for object heap" when making module

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to use Android Studio 0.1 to build a small project for practice, but when I make my module, Android Studio says:

```
Android Dex: [(Module Name)] Error occurred during initialization of VM
Android Dex: [(Module Name)] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, JDK 1.7, with 8GB RAM. I'm not familiar with gradle and don't have an idea how to workaround it. My another almost same PC does not have this problem.

I have tried to modify `studio.exe.vmoptions` in bin folder, and can see the right-down corner change to 742M when I set -Xmx768M. But the error still occurs. Also, if I want to set a larger value like `-Xmx2G`, the `studio.bat` shows:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Then the Android Studio just does not start up.

Is there a way to make my Android Studio usable? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Android studio - [Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760855/3484762%22Solution%22).

Answer (score 12):

For 64 bit users.

1. Click `Start`.
2. type `Environment`.
3. Click `Edit System Environment Variables`.
4. A dialog will pop up, click the button labeled `Environment Variables`.
5. Locate `JAVA_HOME` set it to `C:\Program Files\Java\$YOUR_JAVA_VER` where `$YOUR_JAVA_VER` = jdk1.7.0_21. (You can check your Java version by actually navigating to C:\Program Files\Java\ and looking for your JDK.)

If there is no `JAVA_HOME` you may need to create it.

Comment: This fixed my problem, presumably because Gradle wasn't happy with my 32bit JVM.

Answer (score 6):

setting gradle options lower than default made it work for me.
it depends on the hardware resources that you have access to.

go to
  .settings
    .Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)
      .in VM Options field set -Xmx128m -Xms128m

Comment: Just in case anyone else is seeing this outside Android Studio, this can be set by creating a environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS with value -Xmx512M. http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-1761312/fix-create-java-virtual-machine-issue.html

Comment: @ChrisRae Thanks Chris. I guess your comment should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `File` -> `Settings`.

In the search bar type `heap`.

You'll see highlighted in `Compiler` section `Compiler process heap size`.

There's a couple of other options for heap.

Generally speaking, the search function in the settings of Intellij is rather good.

Comment: @PseudoNinja In my case I had to lower the `Android DX Compiler` heap memory.  By default it was 1024MB and lowering it to 768MB works fine.