# Error:Unable to start the daemon process:

Tags: android-studio

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough
>   space for object heap.

Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's `gradle.properties` file.

For example, the following line, in the `gradle.properties` file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
```

Read Gradle's configuration guide

Read about Java's heap siz

Comment: Is there a question, hidden somewhere?

Comment: My android studio shows this error when gradle synchronisation  occurs.. help me to resolve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle Could not reserve enough space for object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Answer (score 7):

Try this one.

Add this line at the end of your application gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m
```

Answer (score 2):

I had multiple JDK installed in my system. JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8.

And Android Studio was using JDK 1.7. Changing to 1.8 Solved the Issue for me.

Steps I did:

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (File > Close Project).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings.

Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler

Step 4 : Change the Project bytecode version to the highest (currently 1.8).

Step 5 : Close and Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Close Android Studio, go to its install directory, usually "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin," open "studio.exe.vmoptions" with Notepad and change the following lines:
-Xms256m
-Xmx750m
to:
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

restart computer.