# Android Studio1.5 Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, android

When I run my project ,error comes.

```
Starting process 'command 'C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe''. Working     directory: C:\Users\john\AndroidStudioProjects\Prefs\app Command: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\java.exe -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=CN -Duser.language=zh -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\21.1.2\lib\dx.jar com.android.dx.command.Main --dex --verbose --output C:\Users\john\AndroidStudioProjects\Prefs\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\com.android.support-support-v4-21.0.3_42a7fe41e85c69c43b7a4dd1dda945656e9dd165.jar C:\Users\john\AndroidStudioProjects\Prefs\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\21.0.3\jars\classes.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 8,5,main])completed. Took 0.549 secs.
```

I set .gradel.properties  and gradle can be rebuilt and cleaned

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

In C:\User\john\.gradle\daemon\2.8\gradle.properties  I set

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Environment

```
os:windows7 RAM:4G JVM:1.7 android studio 1.5
```

Why the command of 'java.exe -Xmx1024m' is run.When I change this command to "-Xmx512m" and run in the command line ,this command was execute successfully.

How reduce the jvm in this command. I search the issue in SO much times buy not solve the question. 
Please help me ,thanks a lot.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487819/errorunable-to-start-the-daemon-process/31960033#31960033

Comment: I can build the project and start the daemon process, but can't run the app.

Comment: Have you tried with android:largeHeap="true" (inside your manifest)

Comment: run app same errors after i clean project and rebuild project

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true">