# Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: android, api, gradle

Please assign more memory to Gradle.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this code to your **build.gradle**:

```
dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"//2GB or more
}
```

---

If it didn't help use **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31960033/3226984)** answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31760855/3226984).

Comment: @ito2307 have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31760855/3226984) answer?

Comment: Mate i changed to 1024 and -Xmx256m and still saying Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap. Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m and i follow step by step your link.

Comment: @ito2307 hm, how about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31960033/3226984). Try it!

Comment: org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m

Comment: @ito2307 I glad it helped you.