# Error creating new Android project: Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to create a new project in Android Studio, I get the following error.

[image]

**Update**:

This is how my gradle-wrapper.properties (located at `<project_folder>\gradle\wrapper`) looks like:

```
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists 
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: You know... I'm not a Android developer but I've always wondered what a `demon process` is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increse the heap size and Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 1024 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m.

Refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap/31760855#31760855)

Comment: Tried it but no effect. Do I need to select somewhere to use the local project's gradle distribution? http://imgur.com/a/Px99E

Comment: I updated the question with the contents of my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file too...

Answer (score 1):

Try tweaking memory options in gradle.properties file in your project.

Open the gradle.properties file and check these lines

```
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default notes: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Tried it but no effect. Do I need to select somewhere to use the local project's gradle distribution? http://imgur.com/a/Px99E