# Android Studio 2.2 and Jack are getting blocked by Avira Antivirus

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-jack-and-jill, jack-toolchain

So I update my project to use the new jack compiler, but for some unknown reason my AntiVir blocks the task `transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug`
It works if I disable AntiVir real-time protection. I really don't want to do that and I don't want to start putting my android project in the exception list.
I am using Android Studio 2.2 and this is my `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }
}
```

My `project.gradle`

```
buildscript { 
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```

And the error when I try to run the app on my hardware device.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> Failed to delete temporary file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\jill-1475579265083-0.jack
```

Comment: Explain downvote pls.

Comment: Three solutions: Use another Antivirus or add it to exceptions or use the old compiler.

Comment: It's like asking about how to breathe on Mars without oxygen bottle nor Mars terraforming...

Answer (score 8):

While compiling disable real-time protection in your anti-virus package. It is the only workaround that is reliable at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your Android SDK, Android Studio and project folders to your antivirus whitelist. This way you will still be protected while building.

[Guide here](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/900).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha5'

if not working than please add your Android SDK, Android Studio and project folders to your antivirus whitelist:

[Guide](https://www.avira.com/en/support-for-home-knowledgebase-detail/kbid/900)