# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForArmv7aDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-jack-and-jill

So I came across this problem when I am clicking the play button on Android Studio in order to deploy to my device and I cannot figure out how to solve this. Please see print shot attached:
[image: Gradle Message]

I did take certain actions :

1. Rebuild Project (Builds with no problem)
2. Clean Project , (In this case it fails to clean the project)
3. Ran gradlew clean on terminal (failed to clean) with message could not execute clean for ':app:clean'
4. Make Project (no results)
5. Invalidated Caches and Restarted.

None of those actions have taken effect!

Any ideas and solutions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into problems similar to this after forcefully ending some builds which got my caches corrupted somehow.

I would also try to restart the computer and clean the `Temp` folder after that.

If a full restart is overkill, exit Android Studio, run a `gradlew --stop` to kill all the gradle daemons, and/or kill every java process. *Then* try to clear the `Temp` directory

If you're still in a weird state, delete the `.gradle` folder in your project folder (N.B `.gradle`, not `gradle` folder) and as a last resort also try to clear the contents of `C:\Users\manos\.gradle\`

Comment: Hello Mircea, thank you for your comment! Luckily Yesterday I found the solution to this! The problem was my Antivirus, which was blocking Jack from performing system operations! I could not believe my eyes. So you either deactivate your antivirus (on your own risk), or whitelist Jack components! UNBELIEVABLE!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: maybe we should file a bug to the Antivirus company. What AV are you using?

Comment: Also, according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill the jack toolchain is deprecated. Out of curiosity, is there something special you still use it for?

Comment: Yes there is a specific reason! I use signal-r machine for Android. That library was kind of broken for Automatic Transport so I fixed it and build the project! Now that runs only with Java 8 and Jack. Hence the reason am using Jack.

Comment: Regarding the Antivirus, I have seen a couple that do it e.g : ByteFence and  also Avira from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851050/android-studio-2-2-and-jack-are-getting-blocked-by-avira-antivirus. In my case is ByteFence!