# Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1

Tags: java, android, windows-7, android-studio-2.2

[image: Android studio 2.2]

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

Fellow overflowers I hope you can help me with this issue in Windows 7 x86

Comment: I did not used Android Studio but have used Intellij Idea which is Android Studio based on there they have two version of the IDE one is for 32bit and one is for 64bit if your machine is 32bit use the 32bit version.

Comment: The error message clearly says what you should do.  Have you done that?

Comment: It's ok now brow I already find a solution.. thank you!

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap/31760855#31760855

Comment: the error pretty clearly says nothing...  i don't know about you but i don't have a version of "%1" on my computer do you Stephan?  the error is obviously using a variable to note the program/library/tool set that is out of sync but not showing which one...  so which software publisher should i be contacting for a program that isn't given?

Answer (score 21):

[Change in project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfIwb.jpg)

You have to change the jdk location in project structure

Follow those steps

Go to `file -> project structure -> sdk location`

Unselect `Use embedded jdk(recommended)`

Then Change the jdk location to `C)Program Files/java/jdk1.x.x_xxx`

Where `x` is dependent on the JDK version you have installed locally.