# Chromedriver compatibility error with Jenkins server

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I am running a Selenium Webdriver script that includes intatiate chromedriver, but in Jenkins server am getting this error:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestSelenium1\chromedriver.exe" (in directory "."): CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher)
Current working directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TestSelenium1
Selenium version:2.53.1
ChromeDriver: 2.21
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have chromedriver on the jenkins server?

Comment: Yes, chromedriver is there

Comment: Is this helpful? Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635044/errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635044/errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1)

Answer (score 0):

I was using latest Chrome Driver version, but apparently seems like Selenium and Windows Server 2016 supports ChromeDriver 2.33. So when I downgraded the version It worked for me.