# Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android

I'm facing an issue with android studio 3.1.2 . I recently updated it. It shows an error :

```
> CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the
> version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system
> information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit)
> version of the program, and then contact the software publisher
```

I have applied recommended steps about changing the JDK location, but whenever I change location after OK.. it changes again to **USE EMBEDED JDK** automatically.

Please anyone expert help me out on this issue....and sorry for my poor English.

thnx

Comment: It can not change it to the embeded jdk there is something you are doing wrong.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40186773/9130109

Comment: Sir i already mentioned that I have applied procedure which is Mentioned by expert.. but in my case whenever I change location to Java it changes again by itself to USE EMBEDED JDK..