# Error while integragting Agora RTM in my Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, p2p, agora.io

I am developing a chat app and I am trying to integrate the Agora RTM api into my app in order to implement peer to peer text chat but whenever I try to build my project Android Studio gives my this eerror
Error:

CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

I got to say that I am using Android Studio 3.6.0 and my operating system is Windows 10 32 bit

Comment: I found a similar stack overflow post with answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39635044/errorcreateprocess-error-216-this-version-of-1

Comment: I tried it before posting the question but nothing changed