# Android Studio 3.3.1 Out of memory: Java heap space problem

Tags: android, size, heap-memory

I use Android Studio 3.3.1 version and i can not run my application

I can not find any solution in this link[Android Gradle Could not reserve enough space for object heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

I use latest version of java

Out of memory: Java heap space.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*

What is your solutions about this ?

Comment: Add this in manifest.xml in <application> TAG - > android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: I recomenned , If you work virtual machine , delete this virtual machine and create a new one.That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You should go file -> settings -> Instant Run and disable first checkbox.
I hope thats solve